# DevExpress Menu linked to a siteMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, sitemap

I have a MVC4 project with a sitemap and a devexpress menu item on my _Layout page. 
I have a section in my siteMap for InwardsGoods and an index page where the user can QueryDeliveries. The QueryDeliveries is the same page as the InwardsGoods home(Index) page.

```
<siteMapNode url="InwardsGoods/Index" title="Stock and Deliveries"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="InwardsGoods/Index" title="Query Deliveries"  description=""/>
</siteMapNode>
```

When I try to run this it complains about "ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code" Then "The site map file is invalid"

What I dont understand is when I run the siteMap without the url it runs the menu fine, obviously the link to Query Deliveries wont go anywhere though.

```
<siteMapNode url="InwardsGoods/Index" title="Stock and Deliveries"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="" title="Query Deliveries"  description=""/>
</siteMapNode>
```

How can I edit the sitemap to allow for both siteMapNodes to work?

Comment: Please can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this by changing the url to InwardsGoods/Queries and in the controller add an action result

Answer (score 0):

You can't duplicate the url "InwardsGoods/Index" in multiple site map notes.  Change it to "InwardsGoods/Queries" or something in the nested link in the site map.

Comment: Hi there, Could you please clarify more how this will work by changing it to queries and still go to the index page